# allocate a sequence number to items until set items are found unique then jump on to next number in the sequence

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, scripting

allocate a sequence number to items until items are found unique then jump on to next number in the sequence

for example sequence number starts with GST-17/18/SO-004072

items

```
773
773
289
289
912
912
912
912
644
644
644
```

for allocate the first number in the sequence would be like shown below

```
773 GST-17/18/SO-004072
773 GST-17/18/SO-004072
```

and jump on to next unique set of items and so on

```
289 GST-17/18/SO-004073
289 GST-17/18/SO-004073
```

final desired result would be

```
773 GST-17/18/SO-004072
773 GST-17/18/SO-004072
289 GST-17/18/SO-004073
289 GST-17/18/SO-004073
912 GST-17/18/SO-004074
912 GST-17/18/SO-004074
912 GST-17/18/SO-004074
912 GST-17/18/SO-004074
644 GST-17/18/SO-004075
644 GST-17/18/SO-004075
644 GST-17/18/SO-004075
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `awk`:

```
awk -v s='GST-17/18/SO-004072' 'BEGIN{k=s; sub(/^.+-/, "", k)}
p && p != $1{sub(/-[^-]+$/, sprintf("-%06d", ++k), s)}
{print $1, s; p=$1}' file
```

```
773 GST-17/18/SO-004072
773 GST-17/18/SO-004072
289 GST-17/18/SO-004073
289 GST-17/18/SO-004073
912 GST-17/18/SO-004074
912 GST-17/18/SO-004074
912 GST-17/18/SO-004074
912 GST-17/18/SO-004074
644 GST-17/18/SO-004075
644 GST-17/18/SO-004075
644 GST-17/18/SO-004075
```

Learn `awk`:

- [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)
- [Awk Tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may also help you on same.

```
awk -v s1="-" -v num="GST-17/18/SO-004072" 'BEGIN{split(num, array,"-")} prev!=$0 && prev{array[3]++;val=array[1] s1 array[2] s1 sprintf("%06d",array[3])} {val=val?val:num;print $0,val;prev=$1}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too here.

```
awk -v s1="-" -v num="GST-17/18/SO-004072" '
BEGIN{
  split(num, array,"-")}
prev!=$0 && prev{
  array[3]++;
  val=array[1] s1 array[2] s1 sprintf("%06d",array[3])}
{
  val=val?val:num;
  print $0,val;
  prev=$1}
'   Input_file
```

Answer (score -1):

A perl one-liner:

```
perl -lpe '$_=$s=sprintf q{%d GST-17/18/SO-%06d}, $_, ($t//=4071)+=($s!=$_)' in.txt
```

which is equivalent (except for safety checks) to the following long version:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($t,$s)=(4072-1,);
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  no warnings qw(numeric uninitialized);
  if ($s!=$_) {
    $t++;
  }
  $s=sprintf "%d GST-17/18/SO-%06d\n", $_, $t;
  print $s;
}
```